# simpy events synchronization using Container or store

Tags: python, containers, store, simpy

I have a code that implement scheduling using simply. The simulation run processors in parallel in intervals. Moreover, for each interval, there is a synchronization barrier that waits till all processors execution of the tasks and then move to the next interval.
The code is below adopted from https://wso2.com/blog/research/modeling-closed-system-performance-of-a-server-with-discrete-event-simulation/
The code consists of a client which sends a request to an output queue which is examined by servers (processors). Then, servers examine their queue and execute the job in the queue. The problem with this code there is no synchronization; processors don't wait for each other. I need a unified message to be sent to all processors so that they wait for each other. I was thinking of using a container or store but can't seem to wrap my head around them.

For example, if I run 4 processors where each one is executing jobs of different execution times (P1: 4s, P2: 3s, P3: 2s, P4: 1s); processor 1 (P1) is executing a job of 4 seconds length. How can I add synchronizing barrier so it will interrupt processors P2:P4 till 4 seconds have passed?

```
import random
import simpy 
SEED=42
average_processing_time=0.025
response_times=[]
queue_lengths=[]
waiting_times=[]

concurrenncy=4
num_cores=4



def client(env,out_pipe,in_pipe,i):
    global response_times
    while True:
        processing_time=random.expovariate(1/average_processing_time)
        arrival_time=env.now
        d={1:processing_time, 2:i , 3:arrival_time}
        out_pipe[i].put(d)
        #print('cliuent is processing the request %d' % i)
        response=yield in_pipe[i].get(filter=lambda x: True if x[2] == i else False)
        response_time=env.now-arrival_time
        response_times.append(response_time)
        

        
def server (env,in_pipe, out_pipe,i,channel):
    global queue_lengths 
    global waiting_times
    times=[]
    
        
    while True:
        request=yield in_pipe[i].get()
        #request_all=yield in_pipe.get()
        processing_time=request[1]
        arrival_time=request[3]
        waiting_time=env.now-arrival_time
        waiting_times.append(waiting_time)
        #for j in range(num_cores): 
         #  request_all=yield in_pipe[j].get()
            #times.append(request_all[1])
            
        queue_length=len(in_pipe[i].items)
        queue_lengths.append(queue_length)
        print('server %d is processing the request at time %f' % (i,env.now))
        #if max(times) > processing_time:
         #   new_t=max(times)
        #else:
         #   new_t=processing_time
        yield env.timeout(processing_time)
        channel.put(1)
        out_pipe[i].put(request)
        
random.seed(SEED)
in_pipe=[]
out_pipe=[]
p=[]
enviornment=simpy.Environment()
channel=simpy.Store(enviornment)
for i in range(num_cores):
    in_pipe.append(simpy.Store(enviornment))
    out_pipe.append(simpy.FilterStore(enviornment))
for i in range(concurrenncy):
    enviornment.process(client(enviornment,in_pipe,out_pipe,i))
    
for i in range(num_cores):
    t=enviornment.process(server(enviornment,in_pipe,out_pipe,i,channel))
    p.append(t)
enviornment.run(until=enviornment.all_of(p))

response_times=[x*100 for x in response_times]
waiting_times=[x*100 for x in waiting_times]
#print(waiting_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example on how to sync several workers where each worker waits for all the workers to finish before starting the next task

```
"""
    Simple demo where workers wait for all workers to finish before starting next task

    Programer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class Worker():
    """
        simple worker
        waits for a start event
        does some work
        repeat
    """

    def __init__(self, env, id, controler):
        self.env = env
        self.id = id
        self.controler = controler
        self.next_done_event = simpy.Event(self.env)

        self.env.process(self.do_work())

    def do_work(self):
        """
            wait for controler's start event
            do some work
            trigger done event
            repeat
        """

        while True:

            yield self.controler.get_start_event()

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} worker {self.id} has started')

            yield self.env.timeout(random.uniform(1,4))

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} worker {self.id} has finish')

            self.next_done_event.succeed()

            self.next_done_event = simpy.Event(self.env)

    def get_next_done_event(self):
        """
            workers next done event
        """

        return self.next_done_event

class Controler():
    """
        tracks when all the workers have finished
        and broadcasts a done event
    """

    def __init__(self, env):
        
        self.env = env
        self.start_event = simpy.Event(self.env)

        self.workers = []

        self.env.process(self.monitor_workers())

    def add_worker(self, worker):
        """
            workers need to be addeded before sim is started
        """

        self.workers.append(worker)

    def get_start_event(self):
        """
            returns the controler next start event

            Note: that all the workers are gettng the same event
        """

        return self.start_event

    def monitor_workers(self):
        """
            trigger start event
            wait for all workers to finish
            repeat
        """

        # need this to insure all workers are set up
        yield self.env.timeout(1)

        while True:

            self.start_event.succeed()
            self.start_event = simpy.Event(self.env)

            done_events = [worker.get_next_done_event() for worker in self.workers]

            yield self.env.all_of(done_events)

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f} all workers have finished')

# boot it up
env = simpy.Environment()

controler = Controler(env)

for i in range(3):
    worker = Worker(env, i+1, controler)
    controler.add_worker(worker)

env.run(100)
    
print('done')
```